# Moksha According to Shiva and Vasihnav agamas

Tags: vaishnavism, moksha, shaivism, agamas, dvaita

I have heard that the Vaishnava and Shaivite Agamas mention that the Jiva is different from the Param Atma and that during moksha, the Jivas main their individual personality. Can anyone provide these verses (Agamas name, verse number, and verse) because I cannot find English versions of most of them? The more the better.

Comment: moksha mean immortality, not freedom

Comment: there are different shavite schools on this.